# Can I create a BufferedImage from a JPanel without rendering in a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, bufferedimage

Is it possible to create a BufferedImage from a JPanel without first rendering it in a JFrame? I've searched everywhere I can think of and cannot find an answer. Can anyone help?

Here is some sample code. If I don't un-comment the JFrame code, my BufferedImage is blank.

```
    test(){
//      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        Dimension dim = new Dimension(50,50);
        panel.setMinimumSize(dim);
        panel.setMaximumSize(dim);
        panel.setPreferredSize(dim);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("hello");
        panel.add(label);
//      frame.add(panel);
//      frame.pack();
        BufferedImage bi = getScreenShot(panel);

        //...code that saves bi to a jpg
    }

    private BufferedImage getScreenShot(JPanel panel){
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        panel.paint(bi.getGraphics());
        return bi;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477522/jframe-to-image-without-showing-the-jframe

Comment: The other post is still adding the component to a JFrame to render it. I am calling this section of code in a loop, creating an image and saving it to a JPG. The loop executes upward of 2000 times causing the me to run out of heap space.

Comment: @user1680705 have you tried print instead of paint?

Comment: I tried print and it's still blank. To create a BufferedImage, I must pass the width and height of the object into the constructor. Before adding the panel to the frame, both of those values are 0. Even if I set them to an arbitrary size, say 700, the BufferedImage is still blank.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5853992/418556) to [Swing: Obtain Image of JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5853879/418556) as well as [Why does the JTable header not appear in the image?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7369814/418556) for tips on painting components that have not yet been rendered.  I expect the fix to your problem is shown in the label of `LabelRenderTest.java`.

```
JLabel textLabel = new JLabel(title);
textLabel.setSize(textLabel.getPreferredSize());
```

[image]

### Update

```
Dimension dim = new Dimension(50,50);
panel.setSize(dim);  // very important!
panel.setMinimumSize(dim);
panel.setMaximumSize(dim);
panel.setPreferredSize(dim);
// ...
```

Or here is the complete source.  The size of the label also needs to be set.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.*;

public class RenderTest {

    RenderTest() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        Dimension dim = new Dimension(50,50);
        panel.setSize(dim);
        panel.setMinimumSize(dim);
        panel.setMaximumSize(dim);
        panel.setPreferredSize(dim);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("hello");
        label.setSize(label.getPreferredSize());
        panel.add(label);

        BufferedImage bi = getScreenShot(panel);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi)));
    }

    private BufferedImage getScreenShot(JPanel panel){
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
            panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        panel.paint(bi.getGraphics());
        return bi;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new RenderTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: The concern of the OP was that he wanted to do this without using frames, because he ran out of memory when he used frames.

Comment: @lbalazscs  That does not change the fact that a component does not need to be added to *anything* prior to being rendered successfully.  Using the one line tweak shown above (& making an SSCCE) - the panel appeared.

Comment: Andrew, I could not get it to work without adding to a frame and calling pack (I had an image, but did not see the "hello" label on it). I also discovered the missing panel.setSize. I would be interested in your SSCCE.

Comment: @lbalazscs I'd forgotten the label, I just set the BG of the panel red and went with it.  See SSCCE above.  Note there is no frame, no call to `pack()` and everything is rendered before anything appears on-screen.  Abracadabra!

Comment: Andrew, you are right, no frame is necessary +1 and I'll edit my post. (in my test I forgot the label.setSize(label.getPreferredSize()) and that's why it worked only if I called pack() on a frame.

Comment: That did work, but there is one major problem. It's not recognizing any of my layout managers. It starts drawing every single item at 0,0. Is there a way to do this and use layout managers?

Comment: *"one major problem."*  One major Q&A at a time.  Mark this one answered, ask a new question.  I think I know the answer, but post an SSCCE of your best attempt, so I can test my theory.

Comment: Ok. I'll have to use your example with a few modifications (adding a layout manager and a second label), because I'm not allowed to post company source code.

Comment: for those that are interested, here is a link to the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500952/when-creating-a-bufferedimage-from-a-jpanel-w-o-a-jframe-can-i-also-use-a-lay

Answer (score 4):

EDIT2: Basically Andrew Thompson is right in his answer, a frame is not necessary. At the same time it can be practical to have one, because a call to pack() will make the layout managers work. I deleted the first part of my original answer, left is the memory-related part. Note that calling dispose on the Graphics is still needed even without a frame.

About your running out of heap space when using frames: this should not happen. Probably you only need to call [dispose()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29) on the frames when you are done with them. If that does not help, I would suggest asking it in a separate question. From the dispose docs:

> Releases all of the native screen resources used by this Window, its
>   subcomponents, and all of its owned children. That is, the resources
>   for these Components will be destroyed, any memory they consume will
>   be returned to the OS, and they will be marked as undisplayable. (...)
>   Note: When the last displayable window within the Java virtual machine
>   (VM) is disposed of, the VM may terminate.

EDIT: some more thoughts:

- reusing the same JFrame object should also work. Add panel, call pack, create image, remove panel, repeat
- don't forget to call [dispose()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#dispose%28%29) on the Graphics objects created by you as well
- In worst case you can restart the JVM from a script from time to time

Comment: It appears that there may be a memory leak involved in disposing of JFrames, which is why I was hoping to find a way around them. See the following links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376993/does-disposing-a-jframe-cause-memory-leakage  and   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407/remove-top-level-container-on-runtime/6310284#6310284

Comment: So, I do need to add my JPanel to some sort of displayable object to create the buffered image?

Comment: Yes. I think reusing the same JFrame object would also work. Add panel, call pack, create image, remove panel, repeat :)

Comment: I started using the same JFrame object and it did make it all the way through without running out of heap space. I watched the memory usage as it ran, and it still seemed to be leaking a bit. I'll be interested to see if anyone can answer my next question. Thanks for the help guys! New Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500952/when-creating-a-bufferedimage-from-a-jpanel-w-o-a-jframe-can-i-also-use-a-lay