# How do I store the current image of my JPanel?

Tags: java, swing

I wanted to store the current look of my JPanel in order to re-use it as the background for the next iterations of my game loop. I've tried several things that were mentionned on the Internet, but I wanted to do it in a very simple way. 
I'm currently using this to story the current Image of the JPanel:

```
if(needImage){
                Graphics g = tmp.getGraphics();
                g = getGraphics();
                needImage = false;
            }
```

and this to draw it:

```
 g.drawImage(tmp, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), null);
```

Any ideas ?

**Edit:**

I tried this method, found at [Can I create a BufferedImage from a JPanel...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480181/can-i-create-a-bufferedimage-from-a-jpanel-without-rendering-in-a-jframe):

```
   private BufferedImage getScreenShot(JPanel panel){
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
            panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        panel.paint(bi.getGraphics());
        return bi;
    }
```

But it doesn't work right. I'm drawing 1 pixel large rectangles in a loop, in order to draw lines when using the move keys, but it seems to only capture the last point with this method.

```
g.setColor(new Color(hexaR, hexaV, hexaB));
g.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
```

I've taken some screenshots to show you the result:
Original:

**Original Image**

[image]

**Image after some modification**

[image]

As you can see, the original image as been deleted, but it remains the final dots of the "cursor" (x and y inputs of the keyboard). Basically, what I want it to do is to stop the drawing of the lines when I press space, but I want to be able to look where the dots I'm moving are.

I don't know if it clear or not, please tell me. I'll try my best to provide clearer explanations.

Comment: Why do you think `getGraphics` gives you the current image of the JPanel? `Graphics` is a drawing environment, not an image.

Comment: Create a BufferedImage, use its Graphics content to "print" the component

Comment: How do I do that ? I'm not very used to use `Graphics`

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: As an aside, if there is a common BG to different frames of a game, I would draw the BG to a `BufferedImage`, and draw the image to the panel for each frame of the game animation.  I feel the code seen here is taking the wrong approach to achieve the stated goal.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Got it sir! :)

Comment: @ManojKumar  Now that's a classy edit.  I was hoping you'd have the good sense to embed the images when doing the edit.  :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Drawing the BG to a BufferedImage and painting it for each frame is exactly what I want to do. But rather than the expected result, my image gets reset and the only thing that's printed is the last point drawn.

Comment: *"But rather than the expected result,.."*  Time to take this up to the next level, with my most common 'copy/paste comment'... ;)  For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).  Provide a complete (short) example that will run and display the problem, and I'm sure the solution will become clear to someone that happens by the question.