# Remove JFrame in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Fist of all, I knew that this question has been asked before ([JFrame to image without showing the JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477522/jframe-to-image-without-showing-the-jframe)). 
However, due to the poor coding of mine, I would like to ask help from others about how to remove the JFrame out from my coding as shown below:

```
package com.example.ImageScreen;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;  
import java.awt.Graphics;  
import java.awt.Graphics2D;  
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;  
import java.io.File;  
import java.io.IOException;  

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;  
import javax.swing.*;  

//public class ImageScreen extends JPanel{  
public class ImageScreen extends JPanel{  
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  
    private BufferedImage image;  

    public ImageScreen() {  
        setSize(600,600);
   //     setMinimumSize(new Dimension(250,250));  

        try {  
                                                //Load the image  
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/User/Downloads/Geoffs_Picture_Overlay_App/crosshair.gif"));  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }  

    @Override  
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {  
        super.paintComponent(g);  
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();  
                                //Paint it on screen  
        g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null);  
        g2d.dispose();  
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        JFrame window = new JFrame("An Image On Screen");  
                                window.add(new ImageScreen());  
                                window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
                                window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
                                window.pack();  
                                window.setVisible(true);  
                           //     window.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                                window.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                                window.setUndecorated(true);
                            //    window.dispose();

    }  

}
```

Comment: What do you mean `how to remove the JFrame out`, set invisible? dispose? or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Use - `window.setVisible(false)`

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a `JLabel` to display an image. There is no need to do custom painting when you are painting the image at its actual size.
2. The `setUndecorated(...)` method should be invoked before you pack() and make the frame visible.