# Render a table to an image file in Java

Tags: java, image, itext7

I have data in a table of an arbitrary size that I would like to render as an image file. What is the best way to go about this in Java? I can't seem to find any libraries written explicitly for rendering tables.

Example:

I might have three columns ("Col1", "Col2", "Col3") and three rows of data. I would expect output as an image file like this (formatting doesn't need to match exactly):

[image: screenshot of example table]

Possible solutions/workarounds I've considered:

- Using some sort of pdf library to assemble a table and then converting the pdf to an image. I tried itext7, but couldn't manage to render a pdf with a table as an image.
- Using a Swing JTable instance in an [invisible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477522/jframe-to-image-without-showing-the-jframe) JFrame and creating an image from that. The problem with this solution is that I need this code to work in a headless Ubuntu server environment, and it just throws a `HeadlessException`.
- Rendering a LaTeX table with some library, though a quick Google search came up empty for such libraries that can create tables.

Comment: The [Screen Image](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) class might work. There is a simple example showing how to use a JTable in a JScrollPane, without using a JFrame. Maybe this will prevent the HeadlessException? Don't know if the HeadlessException is thrown when trying to create any Swing component or just top level components like JFrame and JDialog?

Answer (score 0):

You can technically render this data in table and generate a PDF and later export it as an image(JPEG/PNG/TIFF,BMP) using pdfRender product of iText 7.
Please refer to this page of iText https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/convert-pdf-to-image-pdfrender